# how to use git commnad create chane file list and commit message to same file?

Tags: git

In my commit history as below

```
commit id "1234ab"  with commit message "commit-msg-1" inclue 
    |_________A_file
    |_________B_file

commit id "7890cd"  with commit message "commit-msg-2"
    |_________C_file
    |_________D_file
```

I use command as below to get change file list between 1234ab and 7890cd.

```
git diff --name-status 1234ab 7890cd

M A_file
M B_file
M C_file
M D_file
```

How to add each file with one commit message as below.

```
M A_file commit-msg-1
M B_file commit-msg-1
M C_file commit-msg-2
M D_file commit-msg-2
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for :

```
git log --oneline --name-status <commit1>..<commit2>

# with your example :
git log --oneline --name-status 1234ab~..7890cd
```

---

You won't have the exact output you describe, if you absolutely need that output (1 line per file, repeat the commit message for each line) you would need to write a script on top of the above command.